# Two dropdowns and a submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two dropdowns with different values in each and have an submit button in last..
Now what i want to do is that, when i select an option form first dropdown and then another option from the second dropdown. Now when i click on submit button it would show there related value popup window having close button  in it.

Code is as follows :

Calling from :

```
<select>
<option>America</option>
<option>India</option>
</select>
```

Calling To :

```
<select>
<option>England</option>
<option>France</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="" value="" />
```

These four countries have four different rates..
When  i select calling from America to England than it ll show a popup window of its rates.
And when i select calling from America to  France than it ll show a pop window  of its own  rates  ..

Thanks in advance if u can help me .. :)

Answer (score 0):

check this out.

http://jsfiddle.net/NFq2f/2/

Comment: Yah its right.. But the problem is that when we select the two countries after that we should click on a button, after than a popup window will appear which should be a customizable div containing some text, calling rate and a close button.. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you just want the selected values or something?
First give the dropdowns a name and/or id.

lets make it simple and just make it a button instead of a submit.

```
<select id="list1">
<option>USA</option>
<option>India</option>
</select>

<select id="list2">
<option>UK</option>
<option>Fr</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Click here" onClick="showAlert();">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showAlert() {
alert('Just get the values in here by ID.selectedItem.text I believe it is');
}
</script>
```

I believe that is basicly what you are after.

P.s.What exactly do you mean with rates?

Comment: I actually want to show a pop up window which contain the calling rates of those two countries that we are selecting in both dropdowns.. The popup window ll actually be a div containing some text with a close button .. Thanks anyway ...

Answer (score 0):

In that case take what Mithin Sasidharan wrote and instead of the links he used just use a page you made and then put the info on that page that you have.

You can also just make a link and style it with CSS to make it look like a button.
If you did that you can simply use

```
<a href="LinkToYourPage" target="_blank"></a>
```

This will make the link open a new window with the page you pointed towards.